# Why printing a reference within the scope and then out of scope retain the same value?

Tags: c++, scope, reference

I'm trying to understand what's going on here;

```
int& FunkyStuff(int num){
    int val = num * 10;
    std::cout << "New value is: " << val << "\n";
    return num;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << FunkyStuff(10) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, when I compile this code without the printing the value within the FunkyStuff function, the main spits out a garbage value which I expect due to the fact that the val object is destroyed once leaving the scope. However, if I just compile the program as is above, the program outputs an expected value of 100 in both cases. What's going on here behind the scenes?

Comment: Because it is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979248/why-does-this-simple-program-result-in-puppies-puppies-puppies-to-the-console).

Comment: You can always check the generated assembly to see why it "works": https://godbolt.org/z/f5fYrM. In my case, it didn't.